# cannot convert html to pdf when file name has a slash

Tags: flutter, dart

I've issue with html convert to pdf when file name have slash(/).

`FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.etelligens/app_flutter/test_insp_CURR/011.html'`..

`test_insp_CURR/011` is a file name with slash.

```
Future savePdf(String htmlContents, String pdfFileName) async {
  Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;
  print(documentPath);
  print(pdfFileName);
  await FlutterHtmlToPdf.convertFromHtmlContent(htmlContents, documentPath, pdfFileName);
}
```

Comment: have you verified that the file is not corrupted? can you convert it using a web app like [Clipperly](https://clipperly.com/convert/document/html-converter) for example?

Comment: @PedroRocha when I change name from `test_insp_CURR/011` to `test_insp_CURR-011` it can be open